# wordpress navigation problem

Tags: wordpress

I have modified style of navigation in style.css. I want to modify of dropdown menu. I have put a single image for main menu. when mouseover the menu, it will change to hover image. but there is a problem when I want to mouseover on child menu, the parent menu (main menu) do not stay with thier hover image but is back to images before hover.
You can preview the website in this link http://alfo.com.my/default/about/company-background/.

I hope that I can get the solution.

Below is the coding of style dropdown modified:

```
/*========Navi========*/
ul#menu-alfo {
    list-style: none;
    }
    ul#menu-alfo li {
        display: inline;

    }
    ul#menu-alfo li a  {
        text-indent: -9999px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        }
        ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-87 a{
            background: url(images/navi.png) no-repeat bottom center;
            width: 118px;       height: 38px;
            }
        ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-86 a{
            background: url(images/navi-02.png) no-repeat bottom center;
            width: 101px;       height: 38px;
        }
        ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-84 a{
            background: url(images/navi-03.png) no-repeat bottom center;
            width: 127px;       height: 38px;
        }
        ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-83 a{
            background: url(images/navi-04.png) no-repeat bottom center;
            width: 116px;       height: 38px;
        }
        ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-85 a{
            background: url(images/navi-05.png) no-repeat bottom center;
            width: 111px;       height: 38px;
            }

            ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-87 a:hover, ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-87 a:active,
            ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-86 a:hover, ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-86 a:active,
            ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-84 a:hover, ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-84 a:active,
            ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-83 a:hover, ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-83 a:active,
            ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-85 a:hover, ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-85 a:active,
            body.page-id-50 ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-87,
            body.page-id-56 ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-86,
            body.page-id-58 ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-84,
            body.page-id-31 ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-83,
            body.page-id-52 ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-85,
            body.single ul#menu-alfo li.menu-item-87{
                background-position: top center;
            }
            ul#menu-alfo ul.sub-menu li {
                margin-left:10px;
                height:13px;
                padding: 6px 0px;


            }
            ul#menu-alfo ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
                margin-left:1px;
                height:13px!important; 


            }               
        ul#menu-alfo ul.sub-menu li a{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #000000;
    font: bold 13px Arial;
    min-width: 170px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: inherit;
        }

        ul#menu-alfo ul.sub-menu a:hover{
            color:#565BBA !important;

        }

        #menu-alfo .menu-header,
div.menu {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 988px;
}
#menu-alfo .menu-header ul,
div.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -17px;
}
#menu-alfo .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#menu-alfo ul ul{background:#fff;}

#menu-alfo ul ul li {

    background-position: top center;

}
#menu-alfo ul ul li a{

color: #FFF;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;

}
#menu-alfo li:hover  a,
#menu-alfo ul ul :hover  a {
    background-position: top center;

}

#menu-alfo ul ul li:hover a,
#menu-alfo ul ul :hover a {

    background-position: top center;

}

#menu-alfo ul ul li:hover  a,
#menu-alfo ul ul :hover  a {

background-position: top center;


}
#menu-alfo ul li:hover  ul {
    display: block;
}



ul#menu-alfo li.current_page_item a,
 ul#menu-alfo li.current-menu-ancestor a,
 ul#menu-alfo li.current-menu-item  a,
ul#menu-alfo li.current-menu-parent a {

    background-position: top center;
    padding:0;  
}
ul#menu-alfo li.current_page_item  a,
ul#menu-alfo li.current-page-menu-ancestor  a,
ul#menu-alfo li.current-page-menu-item  a,
ul#menu-alfo li.current-menu-parent a {

    background-position: top center;
    padding:0;  
}
 ul#menu-alfo li.current-page-ancestor  a {

    background-position: top center;
    padding:0;
}

#menu-alfo ul ul li.current_page_item  a,
#menu-alfo ul ul li.current-menu-ancestor a,
#menu-alfo ul ul li.current-menu-item  a,
#menu-alfo ul ul li.current-menu-parent a {
    background-position: top center;    
    padding:0;
}

#menu-alfo li.current_page_item a:hover {background-position: top center;}
#menu-alfo li.current_page_parent ul li a:hover {background-position: top center;}

* html #menu-alfo ul li.current_page_item a,
* html #menu-alfo ul li.current-menu-ancestor a,
* html #menu-alfo ul li.current-menu-item a,
* html #menu-alfo ul li.current-menu-parent a,
* html #menu-alfo ul li a:hover {
    background-position: top center;
    padding:0;
}


/*=====end navi=====*/

/* =Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#access {

    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
#access .menu-header,
div.menu {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 928px;
}
#access .menu-header ul,
div.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#access .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#access ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul li.menu-item-87 ul  {  /*-----Dropdown with diffrent height------- */
    background:url(images/bgmenu1.png);
    width:200px;
    height:130px;
}
#access ul li.menu-item-85 ul{    /*-----Dropdown with diffrent height------- */  
    background:url(images/bgmenu2.png);
    width:200px;
    height:170px;
}
#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {

}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#access ul li.current_page_item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
    color: #fff;
}
* html #access ul li.current_page_item a,
* html #access ul li.current-menu-ancestor a,
* html #access ul li.current-menu-item a,
* html #access ul li.current-menu-parent a,
* html #access ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is: Can we find a way to use CSS to change the style of an element when a different element is hovered over. I think the answer is 'No'.

So then we need to think about workarounds. Probably the most straight-forward would be to include the glowing menu item in the background image for the submenu. This would mean a different graphic for each submenu and some changes to positioning, etc. There would almost certainly be other issues that you would have to plan for.

As you can see, I haven't thought this through entirely, so please take this as a start point, not a perfect plan.

Indeed, you may conclude that this is not worth the effort for the relatively small benefit. Your choice.

Good luck!